# Is name a special keyword in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I am using Ubuntu and PostgreSql 8.4.9.

Now, for any table in my database, if I do `select table_name.name from table_name`, it shows a result of concatenated columns for each row, although I don't have any `name` column in the table. For the tables which have name column, no issue. Any idea why?

My results are like this:

```
select taggings.name from taggings limit 3;

---------------------------------------------------------------
 (1,4,84,,,PlantCategory,soil_pref_tags,"2010-03-18 00:37:55")
 (2,5,84,,,PlantCategory,soil_pref_tags,"2010-03-18 00:37:55")
 (3,6,84,,,PlantCategory,soil_pref_tags,"2010-03-18 00:37:55")
(3 rows)


select name from taggings limit 3;
ERROR:  column "name" does not exist
LINE 1: select name from taggings limit 3;
```

Comment: try: select "name" from taggings limit 3; I always put column/table name between double quotes, in this way I can name columns/tables like "MySpecialColumn"/"MySuperDuperTable"

Comment: just tested, I can select exactly as you want, without error, everything worked as expected, my postgres version is 8.3, so I think you have a starting point to look for the issue

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a known confusing "feature" with a bit of history. Specifically, you could refer to tuples from the table as a whole with the table name, and then appending `.name` would invoke the `name` function on them (i.e. it would be interpreted as `select name(t) from t`).

At some point in the PostgreSQL 9 development, Istr this was cleaned up a bit. You can still do `select t from t` explicitly to get the rows-as-tuples effect, but you can't apply a function in the same way. So on PostgreSQL **8.4.9**, this:

```
create table t(id serial primary key, value text not null);
insert into t(value) values('foo');
select t.name from t;
```

produces the bizarre:

```
  name   
---------
 (1,foo)
(1 row)
```

but on **9.1.1** produces:

```
ERROR:  column t.name does not exist
LINE 1: select t.name from t;
               ^
```

as you would expect.

So, to specifically answer your question: `name` is a standard type in PostgreSQL (used in the catalogue for table names etc) and also some standard functions to convert things to the `name` type. It's not actually reserved, just the objects that exist called that, plus some historical strange syntax, made things confusing; and this has been fixed by the developers in recent versions.

Comment: In PostgreSQL 9.4.5, this can still be invoked when using a subquery: `select x.name from (select * from t) x;`

Answer (score 4):

According to [the PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html), `name` is a "non-reserved" keyword in PostgreSQL, SQL:2003, SQL:1999, or SQL-92.

> SQL distinguishes between reserved and non-reserved key words. According to the standard, reserved key words are the only real key words; they are never allowed as identifiers. Non-reserved key words only have a special meaning in particular contexts and can be used as identifiers in other contexts. Most non-reserved key words are actually the names of built-in tables and functions specified by SQL. The concept of non-reserved key words essentially only exists to declare that some predefined meaning is attached to a word in some contexts.

The suggested fix when using keywords is:

> As a general rule, if you get spurious parser errors for commands that contain any of the listed key words as an identifier you should try to quote the identifier to see if the problem goes away.