# How can i create a table with one column of enum datatype in postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql

How can I create a table with one column of enum datatype in PostgreSQL database?

**Table name:** `Employee`

**Columns:**

```
ID: Integer

Name: ENUM
```

Below is the query but not sure it is correct or not.

```
CREATE TYPE Name AS ENUM();

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Employee(
    ID integer NOT NULL,
    Name DEFAULT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "Employee_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id)
 );
```

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**1.** In the line

```
Name DEFAULT NULL,
```

you either forgot the name of the column or defining the columns as enum type:

```
myname Name DEFAULT NULL, -- add column name
```

or

```
Name Name DEFAULT NULL, -- add enum type
```

---

**2.** Because ["Name" is a keyword in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416017/is-name-a-special-keyword-in-postgresql) you also have to change the type name. Otherwise it will not work.

---

**3.** However: Your enum type has no values. So you are not able to insert any value. You have to add some enum values:

```
CREATE TYPE name_type AS ENUM('name1', 'name2');
```

---

**Final:**

```
CREATE TYPE name_type AS ENUM('name1', 'name2');

CREATE TABLE Employee2(
    ID integer, 
    myname name_type
);
```

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=a233572811de8b17c29a182b97636c7b)

Comment: For some strange reason... that's because `name` is a keyword: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html although a non-reserved one, so it should work

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I already found it as well and changed the text :)

Comment: Hey - Thanks for the explanation :)

Here, 'myname' is 'Name' according to my column name?

And, I don't want the default value. So can I write like :

CREATE TYPE name_type AS ENUM();

Comment: yes `myname`is the name of the column, `name_type`is the type (the enum type) similar to `integer` or whatelse. Check out the example link :)

Comment: Hey - can you please clarify one more thing :)


By default, if I want to assign NULL value then is it compulsory to give default values here - ('name1', 'name2') 

can I write like : 

CREATE TYPE name_type AS ENUM(NULL); 

or 

CREATE TYPE  name_type AS ENUM(); 

CREATE TABLE Employee2(
    ID integer NOT NULL, 
    myname name_type DEFAULT NULL
);

Comment: Here you can see how to work with DEFAULT values. It's really the same as in every other type: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=80252b7235ca29d8486adf8aff509d2b

Comment: If we don't give any value then it will take Null by default but if I don't mention values here - CREATE TYPE name_type AS ENUM('name1', 'name2'); & I want to give value at runtime then it will throw an error saying that "invalid input values for enum name_type2: "Ayush"  Line xxx" . Is there any solution for that ?

please check here:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=48b06b704f4f1d705b384f3aaa200af9

Comment: An enum is a fixed type. You are not able to enter other values than you defined in the type definition. For example you need a "gender type" then you'll define CREATE TYPE gender AS ENUM ('male', 'female'); That assures that you cannot enter any different values. It seems that enum is not the feature you are expecting, isn't it?

Comment: Now, I have got the idea. Thanks for your effort and time :)

Answer (score 6):

Here you got a simple example, consider to add a name to your enum column at Employee Table, and add some values to your enum.

```
 CREATE TYPE NameEnum AS ENUM('Jony','Bala','Mark');

 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Employee(
    ID integer NOT NULL,
    name NameEnum DEFAULT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "Employee_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id)
 );

 Insert into Employee(ID,name)
 Values(1,  (SELECT enum_first(NULL::NameEnum)))

 Select * from Employee
 Output:
```

[image: Data Output]

Comment: Hey Danial - Thanks for the explanation.

By default, if I want to assign NULL value then is it compulsory to give default values here - ('Jony','Bala','Mark') 

can I write like :

CREATE TYPE NameEnum AS ENUM(NULL); 
or
CREATE TYPE NameEnum AS ENUM(); 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Employee(
    ID integer NOT NULL,
    name NameEnum DEFAULT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "Employee_pkey" PRIMARY KEY (id)
 );

please clarify.

Comment: Well you actually have a command to add values to the enum, so if you consider this answer correct please mark it like that.
Here you have an addition to the code that i gave:
 ALTER TYPE NameEnum ADD VALUE 'new_value';
 Insert into Employee(ID,name)
 Values(2,  (SELECT enum_last(NULL::NameEnum)))
Select * from Employee
Output: 1 : Jony ; 2 : new_value